# How do I create the correct KeyboardEvent objects for a given string of text?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, keyboard-events

I'd like to simulate some keyboard input by dispatching [`KeyboardEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) objects manually. Creating such events involves passing a key code.

Alas, I only have a given string

```
const text: String = "Hello";
```

I can easily get the char code using [`String::charCodeAt`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charCodeAt%28%29), but how can I get the key code? For any given character (say: "H") there may be just a single key code, a key code plus some modifier (in this case: Shift + keycode_of_h) or even multiple key codes. Is there maybe a way to get the key code for a given char code (possibly by considering the keyboard mapping of the user)?

Comment: Do you run your project in air or not? What is the goal of simulating keyboard input? Who is the receiver of those events? How are those strings generated? Maybe you will have to use native extensions, and maybe it will be ok for you to use `TextEvent` instead of `KeyboardEvent`.

Comment: @user1875642: I'm running the code in the Flash player (11.2 and newer), not in AIR. The receive of the event is a [`spark.components.TextArea`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html) control. The goal is to have some sort of Macro-replay tool for Flex. Thanks for mentioning TextEvent, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't need a 100% correct KeyboardEvent in the first place. Instead, there were two things I was missing:

1. A [`flash.events.TextEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TextEvent.html)  needs to be dispatched for plain text (like "Hello") input.
2. The events need to be dispatched to the embedded edit control which can be accessed using the `textDisplay` property.

Comment: glad you figured out another way to do it at least!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too difficult but it will just take a little bit to set up.

First create a dictionary or Object mapping the UTF-8 values to key values like this:

```
var keyCodes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
keyCodes[49] = Keyboard.NUMBER_1; //1
// add the rest of the mappings...
```

Then because you need to specify SHIFT

```
var shiftedKeyCodes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
shiftedKeyCodes[33] = Keyboard.NUMBER_1; //!
// add the rest of the shifted mappings
```

Then create a utility function like this:

```
public function charCodeToKeyboardEvent(charCode:int):KeyboardEvent{
    var event:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP);
    event.charCode = charCode;
    if(keyCodes[charCode]){
        event.keyCode = keyCodes[charCode];
    } else if (shiftedKeyCodes[charCode]){
        event.keyCode = shiftedKeyCodes[charCode];
        event.shiftKey = true;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return event;
}
```

Then loop through your string and do this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < myString.length; i++){
    dispatchEvent(charCodeToKeyboardEvent(myString.charCodeAt(i)));
}
```

EDIT: I updated this to use the constants on the Keyboard class so that it will work independent of device or operating system.

Comment: Ok, but how do you create the mappings? Don't they depend on they keyboard layout, i.e. the same physical key may result in different character codes depending on the keyboard layout?

Comment: The character code values are English keyboard values. For example, if you press Shift+3, charCode is # on a Japanese keyboard, just as it is on an English keyboard.

Comment: let me add to that to say I haven't tried that, but my previous comment is a quote from the adobe docs about it

Comment: But how can I get the *key codes* of the mapping? A given character (say: '#') can have different key codes (i.e. different physical keys) depending on the keyboard layout. The character codes are the English keyboard values, but what about the key code?